# Is it possible to create a robot account in bitbucket without creating a new email account?

Tags: bitbucket

**Introduction**

According to [this article](https://help.github.com/articles/differences-between-user-and-organization-accounts/) a user account could be given to a robot for Continuous Integration purposes.

**Method**

The IT department created a new email account, this was used to login to the git repository, a ssh key was created, the public key added to bitbucket and finally the jenkins user was able to create commits in bitbucket.

**Problem**

As the email account is only used by the robot and the robot itself is not reading emails it feels that the email account is misused.

**Question**

The question is whether it is possible to create a robot account in bitbucket without creating a new email account.

**Discussion**

If there is no separate email account how could bitbucket deviate between the robot account and an existing real user? A unique email account should be used right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some research and comparing various documents it seems that a bot account is basically a real user account and needs a separate email account in order to create such an account as using an email account to register a new account results in, e.g.: `This email account is already in use`.

Combined with quote retrieved from the link that is defined in the question:

> User accounts are intended for humans, but you can give one to a
>   robot, such as a continuous integration bot, if necessary.

It seems to be necessary to create a new email account if a bot account has to be created as:

1. git repositories, like github, bitbucket and gitlab check whether an email account already exists if a new user is created
2. to clarify that the user is a bot and not a human